# Javascript document.form.submit() not working with Firefox 4.0 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, firefox4, javascript

I'm trying to submit a form with javascript. Works fine with Firefox 3.6, but doesn't work  in Firefox4.0 and IE8.

Code:

```
<table>  
     <tr>
     <td>  
     <form action='results.html' method='post' target='_blank' id='<% $question->{ QuestionID } %>'>  
     <input type='hidden' name='SurveyID' value='<% $surveyid %>'  
     <input type='hidden' name='responses' value='<% join ",", map { $_->{ srid } } @textresults %>'/>  
     <input type='hidden' name='question' value='<% $question->{ QuestionID } %>'/>  
Total Responses: (< a href='javascript: submitForm("<% $question->{ QuestionID } %>");' >View All< /a>)  
     </form>  
     </td>  
     </tr>  
</table>  

Javascript:

<script type='text/javascript'>  
function submitForm(id) {  
document.getElementById(id).submit();  
}  
</script>
```

Any Idea what is wrong?

Comment: use `backtick` to give inline code, `{}` button to format code or use `<code>` tags or give enter and enter and 5 space before code

Comment: did you copy/paste this code from your editor?

Comment: By the way the final tr is malformed, it should be `</tr>` not `</ tr>`.

Comment: `javascript:` URIs are deprecated for a long time. Please use `onclick` handlers.

Comment: Actually iam new to stackoverflow. Thanks for your valid information in formatting the code.

Comment: `<input type='hidden' name='SurveyID' value='<% $surveyid %>'` is an element that has not been closed with `>` or `/>`. Browsers generally deal with HTML bugs but perhaps in this case that's the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all close the first input tag like this: `<input type='hidden' name='SurveyID' value='<% $surveyid %>'/>`. Also remove the spaces from the `a` tag, here: `<a href` and here: `</a>`

Comment: That depends on his doctype.. html5 doesn't require closed input tags.

Comment: @Imondria Still there should be at least a `>` at the end of the tag

Comment: After adding the closing input tag It worked in Firefox 4.0 and IE8. Very very thanks. I have a question to u , How it worked in Firefox 3.6 with out that closing tag??

Comment: @Sathyan I guess Firefox 3.6 was more forgiving of unclosed tags

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you add a name property to the form and submit the form like this:

```
function submitForm(id) {  
  document.formname.submit();
}
```